# Find sum of shortest root to leaf path in a binary tree

Tags: c, algorithm, binary-tree, shortest-path

I am trying to implement a function which will return the sum of the shortest path in a binary tree. I am getting the incorrect answer of 8 instead of 4 for the following tree.

```
                                      1
                                     / \
                                    2   3
                                   / \
                                  4   5
```

---

```
int sumOfShortestPath(BinaryTreeNode *root, std::vector<int> vec) {
if(!root) return 0;

static int minPathLength = INT_MAX;
static int pathLength = 0;
static int sum = 0;

vec.push_back(root -> data);
pathLength++;

if(root -> left == NULL and root -> right == NULL) {
    if(pathLength < minPathLength){
        minPathLength = pathLength;
        sum = sum_vector(vec);
        pathLength = 0;
    }
}

sumOfShortestPath(root -> left, vec);
sumOfShortestPath(root -> right, vec);

return sum;
}
```

I believe my logic is correct but i'm unsure where i'm going wrong. Basically, if I encounter a smaller path, I update `minPathLength` and `sum` and reset `pathLength` back to 0 for the next path exploration.

Comment: Try to solve the problem with paper and pencil. And start learning how to use a debugger.

Answer (score 1):

You're kind of on the right track, but I think the static variables are tripping you up some here.  Also, I don't see a reason to keep a list of the values.  You only need just enough information to determine if the left or right branches are the shortest.

Here's my revised version:

```
#include <stdio.h>

class node
{
public:
    node *left, *right;
    int value;

    node (int v) : left(nullptr), right(nullptr), value(v) { }
};

int sumOfShortestPath(node *root, int *cnt)
{
    if (!root)
    {
        *cnt = 0;
        return 0;
    }

    int lcnt;
    int rcnt;

    int lsum = sumOfShortestPath(root->left, &lcnt);
    int rsum = sumOfShortestPath(root->right, &rcnt);

    if (lcnt < rcnt)
    {
        *cnt = lcnt + 1;
        return root->value + lsum;
    }
    else
    {
        *cnt = rcnt + 1;
        return root->value + rsum;
    }
}

node *buildTree()
{
    node *root = new node(1);

    root->right = new node(3);

    root->left = new node(2);
    root->left->left = new node(4);
    root->left->right = new node(5);

    return root;
}

void main(void)
{
    node *tree = buildTree();

    int work = 0;
    int val = sumOfShortestPath(tree, &work);

    printf("Result: %d\r\n", val);
}
```

There are probably much more optimal ways of counting tree lengths than this, but this gets the job done at the end of the day.